# Device not showing up in Device Manager Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, android, device-manager

Today I accidently uninstalled my Android Phone from Device Manager on my Windows 7 PC. The phone is not getting detected by my computer. I have tried to do several things like `Show Hidden devices` etc but the phone is not getting listed.

Kindly guide me how can I view my android phone back in the device manager!

Now the phone is getting detected with correct name in device manager but I am unable to install usb adb driver as before and receiving an error.

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Check if the phone is set up to work in the correct mode (MTP etc.) Disconnect and reconnect the phone, it should show up. If you still can't see it, then it must show under a different name (as a modem or so).

Comment: what do you mean by mtp?

Comment: MTP is Media Transfer Protocol, connection mode where your device is accessible in a way similar to flash drives and doesn't require additional drivers to exchange files.

Comment: now the phone is getting detected with the correct name but I am unable to install usb adb drivers and get an error. I am updating the question kindly see it

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the drivers for your phone again. As an example, download Samsung Kies if it's Samsung, LG phone tools for LG, etc. They will include the drivers needed for Windows to detect the device

Comment: umm. I downloaded a zip file from the company website and then went to update drivers and manually browsed the folder where they were downloaded

Comment: I did that again but didn't work. I want to root my android phone so thats why I need these drivers

Comment: I can't use the recommended method `http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Win7` because the phone is so thoroughly unrecognized that it is completely invisible to device manager. Every set of instructions I have found assumes it is in there but just not working.